# Dealing with NULL time values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been tasked to make an employee schedule in excel, and I am relatively new to excel. I have figured out how to subtract the end time for a day for an employee from the start time to get the amount of time the employee is scheduled to work each day. These fields are of type time.

Essentially, I need to add the time the employee worked each day to a week time total column and display that. The problem I am having is if there is no start time and/or no end time filled in for a specific day. The blank or null value ruins the formula.

I want to avoid entering a default value to assure the formula doesn't get screwed up, and would rather leave the start time and end time fields blank if the employee is not working that day so that it is more clear to the employee that he or she is not working that day.

So how do I deal with the possibility of a null value and how do I get the total time into a proper decimal number? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need an IF clause, like `=IF(Cell reference starttime = ""; 0; your current formula)`

Comment: Can you make this question concrete by showing us some data?

Comment: To get the total time into a proper decimal number, you can change the format to 'Number'.

Comment: assuming A2 as start time, B2 as end time,=IF(AND(A2<>"",B2<>""),(B2-A2),0), this formula will not add to error

Comment: Hi Apurv, your comment works. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` function to count how many times there are, e.g. this formula will return a blank unless you have times in both `A2` and `B2`

`=IF(COUNT(A2,B2)=2,B2-A2,"")`

format as `h:mm`

That gives the result as a time value like 7:30 - if you want a decimal number of hours like 7.5 then multiply by 24

`=IF(COUNT(A2,B2)=2,(B2-A2)*24,"")`

format as `number`

and if you might have shifts that cross midnight like `23:00 - 07:00` then you can add in a `MOD` function to accommodate that too

`=IF(COUNT(A2,B2)=2,MOD(B2-A2,1)*24,"")`

In all cases for weekly total use `SUM` function to sum the cells with the above formula so that any blanks are ignored, e.g. with daily hours in `C2`, `F2` and `I2` use this formula for the total

`=SUM(C2,F2,I2)`

Comment: Great answer. Leads to other questions I have about MOD and such, but you answered this question very well. Thank you.

Comment: No problem - happy to answer any simple follow-up questions - if it's more involved then just post a new question